# Route rename and redirect producing wrong URL helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am trying to change the route of `/felines` within my app to `/cats`, and I would like to do this while making as few changes to my app code as possible (i.e. not renaming model, controller, or references to URL helpers).

In `routes.rb` I am doing

```
get '/felines', to: redirect('/cats')
resources :cats, as: 'felines'
```

- which serves `FelinesController#index` at `/cats` - good
- and redirects `/felines` to `/cats` - also good

But when debugging, I found that

- `new_feline_path` is `/cats/new` - good
- `felines_path` is `/felines` - BAD!

I also found that `felines_path` will become `/cats`, as desired, if I switch the order of the two lines in `routes.rb`.

Why does the order of those lines affect the value of `felines_path`?

Is there a better way I could achieve the re-routing and redirection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
get '/felines', to: redirect('/cats')
```

rails generates `felines_path` route helper for the above route and since the priority is from top to bottom, `felines_path` will point to /felines. That is the reason why it points to `/cats` when you change the order.

Assign a different name for your custom route so it doesn't override your `felines` path

```
get '/felines', to: redirect('/cats'), as: 'felines_redirect'  #or someother name like that
```

Comment: Awesome!  Couple follow-up questions: 1. Why wasn't `new_feline_path` also subject to the top-down priority?  2. Does the value of `felines_redirect` matter at all, beyond being different from existing routes?

Comment: Nothing is really overwriting `new_feline_path`. Its generated by `resources :cats, as: 'felines'`. Value of `felines_redirect` doesn't matter unless you are planning on using the helper somewhere in your view. We are adding it just to make rails not use the default.